# LDAP Query for nested groups across forests

Tags: active-directory

I have an environment with 2 AD Forests with a domain in each. They have full trust between them.

Forest A with Domain A has a security group called "groupA" which contains a group from Forest B called "groupB". GroupB has a number of users in it.

Now I want to query GroupA and retrieve all the members from GroupB.

I have tried the following LDAP-query:
(&(objectClass=user)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GroupA,OU=Groups,DC=domainA,DC=NET))

That handle nested grouping, but it does not seem to work across forests, it works fine if I only query groupB.

How can I achieve this?

It's used for an application called CA Privileged Identity Manager.

Thanks

Comment: Try to query both domains with the same search and combine the results. The members of groupB should be found if you query domainB.

Comment: maybe you should ask this on serverfault